# Text inside span should overflow on div with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I am not able to see my full text after implementing an ellipsis. I want to see the full text on hover and looking forward to see in the same line. I tried doing this but had no luck.

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. LoremLorem ipsum dolor sit amet.12345</p>x
</div>
</div>
```

```
.box {
width: 600px;
height: 2em;
position: relative;
background-color: #ddd;
}
.box > div {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
}
.box-left {
left: 0;
width: 250px;
}
.box-left > p {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.box-right {
right: 0;
width: 350px;
}

.box-left:hover {
width: 100%;
}

.box-left:hover + .box-right {
display: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dp6Xs/67/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add

```
.box-left > p:hover {
  text-overflow: shown;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

to your CSS and have the entire line be visible at a time. This won't expand the `.box` class's width, though, so you will be overflowing the background color. A quick solution to this would be to just have your box's hover state be the one that triggers expanding the text.

```
.box:hover {
  width: auto;
}

.box:hover .box-left p {
  overflow: visible;
  text-overflow: shown;
}
```

How you go about doing that would be dependent on your end-goal, though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `.hover` event

```
.box-left > p:hover {
  text-overflow: shown;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp6Xs/76/)

Comment: i didn't see any changes, its still not showing full text.

Comment: You said you wanted hover. If you hover over the text it shows all of it

Comment: if you can see text is ending with 12345 but its not coming.

Comment: I have issue to display full text if div is ending. for example in example **http://jsfiddle.net/dp6Xs/80/** i have text **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 123456789 ######** . on hover its only displaying **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 12** as div width is 400px. now here i dont want to see full text which is ending with # without increasing width of div. hope i am more clear now.

Comment: OK. I will update my answer. So you don't want anything do for hover?

Comment: that full text should come on hover only.